# Only one WiFi network not detecting

Tags: wifi

I'm using elementary OS 6. Currently my home WiFi router is not visible on WiFi networks so i have to connect my mobile to WiFi and make hotspot to access internet.

When scan WiFi all other networks are listed in list except my home router. I don't this this related to new OS but this is so annoying.

What could be the problem? any suggestions?

**Update**

I don't think the router is not compatible because sometimes suddenly it show up on WiFi list and can work normally but it disappears after a while. More impotently if i reset my WiFi router it shows up and works as normally. but after a day or two days this happens again.

Also it's not hidden because since sometimes i connects i have that WiFi saved in list so when i trying to connect it shows disconnected.

Router model is `Huawei B312-926`

Output of `sudo lshw -c network`

```
*-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 32
       serial: 9c:b6:d0:d5:12:8b
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=5.11.0-34-generic firmware=WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00140-QCARMSWPZ-1 ip=192.168.***.*** latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:142 memory:dd200000-dd3fffff
```

Output of `sudo lsusb`

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f3:21d4 Elan Microelectronics Corp. Touchscreen
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0cf3:e301 Qualcomm Atheros Communications 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 09da:c10a A4Tech Co., Ltd. USB Mouse
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 1bcf:2b95 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. Integrated_Webcam_HD
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Output of `lspci`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 (rev 06)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 07)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Thermal Subsystem (rev 31)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 31)
00:15.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 31)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 31)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation HM170/QM170 Chipset SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 31)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #2 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
00:1d.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #13 (rev f1)
00:1d.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #15 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM170 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Power Management Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family SMBus (rev 31)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M] (rev a2)
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 32)
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
04:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Toshiba Corporation XG4 NVMe SSD Controller (rev 01)
```

Comment: A little more information will be needed to offer an answer. Can you [edit] your question to include the brand and model of your computer, and perhaps the Terminal output of `sudo lshw -c network`, `sudo lsusb`, and `sudo lspci`? This will provide information about your hardware, making it possible to see if your machine is using the correct driver for the network card 

Comment: I think your router is using 5Ghz band but your wifi adapter supports only 2.4Ghz. Confirm this, if I am correct. Btw on what device you are running elementary os on i.e. laptop or desktop?

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: It's a laptop Dell xps 15, I have updated the question.

Comment: Hmm ... the QCA6174 has a history of being a little finicky on various Linux distributions with no clear solution that works for everybody. One additional question: do you have power-saving for the device turned off? This can sometimes ensure the network connection remains active (even when it's not idle)

Comment: @matigo I'm not using any power-saving options.